# Are there any sephardic customs for a pidyon haben?

Tags: minhag

I am persian and my wife is iraqi. We are looking to find sephardic and especially customs from our background to do at our son's pidyon haben. I believe it adds a lot to include customs beyond doing the basic of halacha.

Comment: Welcome skald89. Looking forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Don't you think that it would be wise to contact a Persian community in this case? They're all over the world, I'm they'd be happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

The following differences are ones I have seen by Sefardim that is different than Ashkenazim.

1 - Sefardim have a custom that the Kohain takes a Hadas - Myrtle leaves - and makes a Bracha of Borei Atzel Besamim.

2 - By Sefardim the Kohain holds the baby. By Ashkenazim the baby is placed in front of the Kohain.

3 - Ashkenazim for the most part do the Pidyon only in the dayime. Sefardim do the Pidyon in the evening also.

[Why are Pidyon HaBen ceremonies done towards evening?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29066/why-are-pidyon-haben-ceremonies-done-towards-evening)

Here is a [audio link](https://net-sah.org/audio/20026) for some Sephardi Pidyon HaBen customs